# How to fix font rendering (no anti-aliasing) in Unity global menu and search?

Tags: unity, 11.10, appmenu, font-rendering

Since I've upgraded my system to Ubuntu 11.10, Unity's global menu and search are having font rendering problems (no anti-aliasing, bad font sizes). No problem in sub-menus.

The font rendering problems do not appear on a newly created user. Just the ones which were existing before the upgrade.

What can I do to solve the rendering problems ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that to resolve this antialiasing problem you need to

```
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
```

In my case I had also lost the background and icons order, but it fixed after a reboot.

Comment: +1 Worked fine for me with a logout on 14.04.  Doesn't appear to have caused any other issues with icon ordering etc.

Comment: In my case, I lost all my icons, desktop settings (keyboard, mouse, etc) but a reboot didn't fixed it. Fortunately I backed up the file before removing. I would strongly suggest against removing the file.

Answer (score 17):

You can adjust the font settings using [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]. Do note that installing gnome-tweak-tool also installs gnome-shell.

To install gnome-tweak-tool, you can run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After installing it, open the tool and go to Fonts. The configurations that you should be changing are 'Hinting' and 'Antialiasing'.

[image]

Information about the options available:

> The type of antialiasing to use when rendering fonts. Possible values
>   are: "none" for no antialiasing, "grayscale" for standard grayscale
>   antialiasing, and "rgba" for subpixel antialiasing (LCD screens only).
>
> The type of hinting to use when rendering fonts. Possible values are: "none" for no hinting, "slight" for basic, "medium" for
>   moderate, and "full" for maximum hinting (may cause distortion of
>   letter forms).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll try to solve the problem this way on the next computer I'll upgrade. The 3 machines I've upgraded until now have had the problem. Meanwhile, I solved it by removing "~/.config/dconf/user" to completely reset the parameters. It is quite radical and some parameters must be reconfigured manually but it works...

Comment: Jokerdino's solution doesn't improve the antialiasing problem. Removing ~/.config/dconf/user does.

Comment: From the Ubuntu forums [1], another solution using dconf-editor (from the dconf-tools package): modify the org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings key [1] http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11322965

Comment: This solution lead me to unity-tweak-tool,  which does the same for unity (at least on 16.10)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the *Text Scaling Factor* to something different from 1.0 (e.g. 1.1 for me is pretty good) and leave *Antialiasing* set to *Rgba*.