# How can I update my graphic card?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, radeon, gpu-driver

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Below is my details:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]

 lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20e0
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2115
    Kernel driver in use: i915


lspci -vs 01:00.0

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]
```

I am having smudges as I previously posted here: [Why am I experiencing visual corruption with Intel X4500 graphics card on 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527564/why-these-smudges-happening-on-my-desktop)

Any advice is very appreciated. I always reboot my computer to solve it temporarily.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `lspci -vs 01:00.0` to [your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/602103/edit)?

Comment: Thank you Wilf. It gives me: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]. Thank you.

Comment: Did you give [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](/q/124292/175814) a try?

Comment: try updating drivers like he said^^
try removing the card and using onboard graphics for a bit to see if that fixes it
if that fixes it its probably a bad card

Comment: Also, just t be sure what GPU you are currently using - please post the results of `glxinfo |grep vendor`.

Comment: Is that font an aliasing /text rendering problem?
See this thread for fixes. http://askubuntu.com/questions/68022/how-to-fix-font-rendering-no-anti-aliasing-in-unity-global-menu-and-search

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to tell you this - but those smudges are a clear sign that your HD3650 is starting to fail. Especially if they become more frequent the longer you use the computer.

I had that same issue on the same card on a laptop of mine.

Regardless, if you want to exclude a driver problem, you can just download an image of a later (14.10) or earlier (I would recommend 12.04 based on the card) Ubuntu, [write it to a USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), boot it, use it for a while and check if the issue remains.

Unfortunately the issue is all too familiar to me. The "smudges" started as really small glitches, in 3D or composited images, and then grew to what you see now. In a later stage, most of the screen started getting "garbled".

The potential goo news is that replacing the card on my laptop with one from ebay solved the issue for me. Although it is not a task for a beginner.

[Here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-replace-your-broken-8600m-gt-graphics-card-in-the-i-fl90.513588/) is the guide I followed for my own laptop.

Of course, this will vary with the laptop, and in some cases it may not even be possible to swap cards.

I hope this is not the issue with your own card, but if it is I hope I have provided you with some options.

## Update:

After looking more carefully at the picture, this does not look like your typical failing card error (although I wouldn't completely discard the possibility).
This can also be an [issue with hyperz](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75112).
You can try to disable it by editing `/etc/profile` and adding this line to the bottom:
`R600_DEBUG=nohyperz`
After adding this line, just restart your machine and see it it has helped.