# Text rendering issues in Matlab after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, graphics, matlab

I'm having various issues with rendering text in Matlab 2016b after doing the upgrade to 16.04. Here are some example screenshots:

[image: Glitching in menu]

[image: Invisible text in profiler]

I have already checked the classic Ubuntu issue with sub-pixel anti-aliasing causing text to disappear, but this does not seem to be the issue.

lshw gives the following output:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 845M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

*Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?*

Comment: I wouldn't: I would add the graphics tag so the next user looking for the same problem will find it easier...  Also: delete all of your comments to keep things tidy here as it's starting to look like a chat room here!  **:D**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the output of the `lshw` command, I can safely conclude you forgot to install the nVidia drivers...

So [have a look here on how to install them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) and then the problem will go away!

#### :-)

Answer (score 2):

For those of us who don't happen to have a spare NVIDIA card lying around: I think the problem is related to the Intel driver and can be fixed by [enabling antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487668/matlab-profiler-text-is-not-rendered-properly-in-ubuntu/41175653#41175653).

Enabling font antialiasing in MATLAB:

Select *Preferences* -> *Fonts* -> [x] *Use antialiasing to smooth desktop fonts* (requires MATLAB restart)

Comment: I had no idea that Matlab had it's own setting for this. This is actually a system wide issue with Ubuntu on some laptops, so I might add that the steps from the following answer (on another question) should be followed if this is the source of the issue: http://askubuntu.com/a/68029/616016 This is just based on my experience however, I have not done any targeted testing.